# kstemmer and protwords

Tags: solr, lucene, filterfactory

Friends,

I currently using KStemmer to perform the stemming operations in my application i develop with solr. What is found is when we use kStemmer , it is not taking the protwords.txt

```
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>

  </analyzer>
```

It is not taking the words in the protwords as protected. Is this how Kstem works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source code but I couldn't see the implementation.Btw, I checked source-code of the Solr 3.6.

It is implemented in the [SnowballPorterFilterFactory](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_6/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/analysis/SnowballPorterFilterFactory.java) but not in [KStemFilterFactory](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/branches/lucene_solr_3_6/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/analysis/KStemFilterFactory.java).

Comment: Can we implement that in KstemFilterFactory, is it feasible?

Comment: You can implement your own filter factory which combines the KstemFilterFactory and SnowballPorterFilterFactory.